# Client And Server Socket Connection using C#

Tags: c#, client-server, serversocket, tcplistener, asyncsocket

I created two projects one with client and other with server to exchange  text between both of them;on same computer i run those exe. 
MY Client Side Connection Code connection looked :

```
 using (SocketClient sa = new SocketClient(host, port))   
    {   
    sa.Connect();   
    Console.WriteLine(sa.SendReceive("Message #" + i.ToString()));   
    }   
    sa.Disconnect();
```

while socketclient is my class which contain these methods and constructor:

```
internal SocketClient(String hostName, Int32 port)   
{   
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);    
IPAddress[] addressList = host.AddressList;      
this.hostEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addressList[addressList.Length - 1], port);     
this.clientSocket = new Socket(this.hostEndPoint.AddressFamily,      SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);    
}      
internal void Connect()    
{     
SocketAsyncEventArgs connectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();    
connectArgs.UserToken = this.clientSocket;    
connectArgs.RemoteEndPoint = this.hostEndPoint;     
connectArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnConnect);     
 clientSocket.ConnectAsync(connectArgs);     
 autoConnectEvent.WaitOne();     
SocketError errorCode = connectArgs.SocketError;     
 if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)     
{   
throw new SocketException((Int32)errorCode);     
}      
}      
internal void Disconnect()     
{    
 clientSocket.Disconnect(false);     
 }     
private void OnConnect(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)    
 {     
 autoConnectEvent.Set();    
 this.connected = (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success);    
 }     
internal String SendReceive(String message)    
{    
 if (this.connected)     
{     
Byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);      
SocketAsyncEventArgs completeArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();     
 completeArgs.SetBuffer(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);   
 completeArgs.UserToken = this.clientSocket;   
  completeArgs.RemoteEndPoint = this.hostEndPoint;   
  completeArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnSend);     
 clientSocket.SendAsync(completeArgs);    
  AutoResetEvent.WaitAll(autoSendReceiveEvents);      
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(completeArgs.Buffer,    completeArgs.Offset,completeArgs.BytesTransferred);     
}   
else    
{       
throw new SocketException((Int32)SocketError.NotConnected);     
}     
}
```

while on server side code looks like that:

```
SocketListener sl = new SocketListener(numConnections, bufferSize);     
sl.Start(port);     
Console.WriteLine("Server listening on port {0}.   
Press any key to terminate the server process...", port);       
Console.Read();       
sl.Stop();
```

Socket listener is my class which contain this method and constructor :

```
internal SocketListener(Int32 numConnections, Int32 bufferSize)    
 {     
  this.numConnectedSockets = 0;  
  this.numConnections = numConnections;  
 this.bufferSize = bufferSize;      
 this.readWritePool = new SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(numConnections);     
 this.semaphoreAcceptedClients = new Semaphore(numConnections, numConnections);      
 for (Int32 i = 0; i < this.numConnections; i++)     
{     
SocketAsyncEventArgs readWriteEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();     
readWriteEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs> (OnIOCompleted);      
readWriteEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[this.bufferSize], 0, this.bufferSize);    
this.readWritePool.Push(readWriteEventArg);    
}       
}  
internal void Start(Int32 port)   
{     
 IPAddress[] addressList = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).AddressList;     
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(addressList[addressList.Length - 1], port);     
this.listenSocket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);     
this.listenSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = this.bufferSize;      
            this.listenSocket.SendBufferSize = this.bufferSize;     
if (localEndPoint.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)     
{     
this.listenSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, (SocketOptionName)27, false);     
this.listenSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, localEndPoint.Port));     
}     
else     
{     
this.listenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);    
}    
this.listenSocket.Listen(this.numConnections);     
this.StartAccept(null);      
 mutex.WaitOne();     
}
```

I have already port forward of my router because of server side exe which didn't    listen without port forwarding.
    it is working fine with send and receive on same pc and same port at home.
    While when i try to run both of codes exe on my office computer it throws     exception at following line:

[Exception thrown by socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0elzM.png)

Could any one guide me whats the problem and how to resolve it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried temporary disable your Windows firewall ?

Comment: I can't because there is a server at my office which operates by network engineer i can't tell him to do because it would be security issue.i too might think that this is a firewall blocking issue can't i resolve it through having some code logics...any source...thanks

Comment: You may try the port 80 instead of a custom one to see if they're open.

Comment: i try using that ports but it responds that  port is already in use

Comment: Since you first tried at home locally, don't you have multiple computers to test it without your company security ?